SSRS stored procedure expression text
I'm converting an SSMS EXEC <stored procedure> to Snowflake CALL <stored procedure>, but I'm getting an error on syntax, and I'm seeking assistance on the expression text that I maybe missing a character or so.
="CALL PRD_DB.DW_RPT_SC.USP_CLIENT_REPORT_ZERO_PARAMTER_VALUES(
    to_date('" + FormatDateTime(Parameters!Start_Date.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate) + "'),
    to_date('" + FormatDateTime(Parameters!End_Date.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate) + "'),'" + 
    "PRD_DB.DW_RPT_SC.USP_CLIENT_REPORT_ZERO_PARAMTER_VALUES.VQ_NAME'" + ");"



I modified the code snippet to the above, and i'm still getting the same error. The "VQ_NAME" is being passed to the SP that pulls from the actual table distinctly to pull data for the VQ Name parameter.

The error message indicates that the database schema has not been specified for the query. Depending on how the stored procedure is executed, you either need to include the schema in the connection or session, or you need to execute USE SCHEMA <database.schema> prior to calling the proc.
